# Check if HTML row inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie in HTML and JavaScript world. Basically, I'm trying to validate an HTML table.

I wanna validate on form submit, if any of the elements (inputs or selects) on a table row have a value all the row elements must be completed. For example:

- if all the elements (inputs or selects) on a row are empty then it's Ok
- if all the elements (inputs or selects) on a row are completed then it's Ok
- if only 1, 2 or 3 elements (inputs or selects) on a row are completed then it's not ok (you must complete all of them or none of them), I wanna show an alert to indicate that all the row elements must be completed.

I'm trying to help me to understand how to resolve this problem by searching online. I'm struggling to adaptate the below code to do that:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>subtype</th>
                <th>quantity</th>
                <th>attachment</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="q">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="w">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="e" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="r">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="t">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="y">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="u" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="i">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="o">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="p">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="a" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="s">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="d">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="f">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="g" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="h">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="j">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="k">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="l" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="m">
            </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
    function validate(frm) {
        var tb = frm.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var trs = tb.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i=0; i < trs.length; i++) {

            var inputs = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("input");

            if (!validateEmpty(inputs[0]) || !validateEmpty(inputs[1])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
            return true;
    }

    function validateEmpty(obj) {
        if (obj.value == "") {
            alert("empty!");
            obj.select();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

Can you help me to resolve this? Thxs.

UPDATE!

```
<script>        
function validate(frm) {
    const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#myform tr')];
    const isValid = trs.every((tr) => {
      const inputs = [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')];
      const selects = [...tr.querySelectorAll('select')];
      if (
        inputs.every(input => input.value.length === 0) &&
        selects.every(select => select.selectedIndex === 0)
      ) {
        // valid:
        return true;
      }
      return (
        inputs.every(input => input.value.length > 0) &&
        selects.every(select => select.selectedIndex !== 0)
        alert("empty!");
      );
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_required.asp) attribute? It specifies that the element must be filled out before submitting the form.

Comment: You could use required attribute but then make sure you trim the value so people can't enter space and submit. Because technically space will validate the required attribute

Comment: thxs @dzimiks, but I believe that I expressed myself badly. I cannot use the required attribute because it will make all the inputs and selects of the table mandatory. It isn't the idea: I wanna make mandatory all the inputs and selects only in the same row, only if one of them is completed (if in another row all of the selects and inputs arent filled then its ok, i dont wanna ask to complete them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy, just iterate over all `trs`, and iterate over each `input` and `select` inside. Use the `Array` methods to make the syntax easiest:

```
const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#myform tr')];
const isValid = trs.every((tr) => {
  const inputs = [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')];
  const selects = [...tr.querySelectorAll('select')];
  if (
    inputs.every(input => input.value.length === 0) &&
    selects.every(select => select.selectedIndex === 0)
  ) {
    // valid:
    return true;
  }
  return (
    inputs.every(input => input.value.length > 0) &&
    selects.every(select => select.selectedIndex !== 0)
  );
});
```

I'm using `input.value.length` rather than just a boolean check of `input.value` so that inputs of `0` will be accepted as valid as well.

Here's a live snippet that uses `Array.from` instead, in case you're using an ancient browser:

```js
document.querySelector('#myform').addEventListener('submit', validate);
function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#myform tr'));
  const isValid = trs.every((tr) => {
    const inputs = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('input'));
    const selects = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('select'));
    if (
      inputs.every(input => input.value.length === 0) &&
      selects.every(select => select.selectedIndex === 0)
    ) {
      // valid:
      return true;
    }
    return (
      inputs.every(input => input.value.length > 0) &&
      selects.every(select => select.selectedIndex !== 0)
    );
  });
  console.log(isValid);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="myform">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>subtype</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>attachment</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="q">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="w">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="e" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="r">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="t">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="y">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="u" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="i">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="o">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="p">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="a" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="s">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="d">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="f">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="g" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="h">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="j">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="k">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option>option 4</option>
                    <option>option 5</option>
                    <option>option 6</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="l" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="m">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: hi @certainperformance! thxs for your answer. Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm trying to adaptate your code to mine and I have some doubts: I change all the script  part and put your code into my function (I put it below the 'UPDATE!' in the original answer). The three dots (...) have a relationship with the array methods?. 
I can not make it work.

Comment: `...` is the spread operator - it converts an array-like object into an array. I used it here to make it easy to iterate over the elements in question with `every` tests. See my edit: I made a live snippet.